# iOS Swift how detect login error reason to show proper error alert to the user

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, closures

I need to create login function for my app, the API retrieves an authentication token in case of successful login.
In my current implementation the network layer performs the API call and passes back a closure with boolean (depending on login result) and String token (which I need in the viewController who requested the login).

My problem is that I would like to show proper alert to user depending on login failure reason (Eg. No connection, wrong password). 
With this implementation I see I am not able to achieve this result. Could someone give me some help to improve my solution?

Here is my code:

```
    public func load(_ urlString: String, email: String, password: String, withCompletion completion: @escaping (_:Bool,_ token: String) -> Void) {

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "email": email,
        "password": password
         ]
        do {
           urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
           } catch let error {
        }

        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            guard let data = data,
                let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil else {                                              
                    return
        }

            guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    
            completion(false,"")
            return
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        do{

            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
            print(jsonResponse) //Response result

            let token: String = jsonResponse?["token"] as! String
            completion(true,token)
        } catch let parsingError {
            completion(false,"")
            return
        }
    })
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

My view Controller

```
        network.load(NetworkController.loginURL,email: email, password: password) { [weak self] (result :Bool, token: String) in
             if result{
                 print("Successful Authentication with token \(token)")
             }
             else{
                 print("Authentication failed")
                 //show Error alert
             }
          }
```

Comment: Your completion block could include the error as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add completion block for error too as error can happen too.

```
public func load(email: String, password: String, success: @escaping (token: String) -> (), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {

//your code here

}
```

If you don't want to specify seperate completion for success and failure please refer to Davydov Denis's answer. The error will be nil if it succeeds and vice versa.

> Also specify your Base URL in a seperate constant file and add only /login for easy understanding and clean code.

Answer (score 0):

you should use completion like this:

```
completion: @escaping (success token: String?, failure error: Error?) -> Void)
```

if you got a data `completion(success: token, failure: nil)`

and if you got an error, `completion(success: nil, failure: error)`